# A fair 6-sided die is rolled 6 times, what's the probability the outcome has exactly 2 or 3 elements?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A fair $6$-sided die is rolled $6$ times independently. For any outcome, this is the set of numbers that showed up at least once in the different rolls. For example, the outcome is $(2,3,3,3,5,5)$, the element set is $\{2,3,5\}$. What is the probability the element set has exactly $2$ elements? how about $3$ elements?

I know the sample space is $6^6$. The counting for $2$ elements is $6C2 \cdot 6!$? I would really appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Please see this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to format mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly two numbers appear:

There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways for two of the six numbers to appear.  On each of the six rolls of the die, there are two possible outcomes, giving $\binom{6}{2} \cdot 2^6$ possible outcomes in which two of the six numbers appear.  However, of these $2^6$ sequences, there are two in which the same number is rolled six times.  Thus, the probability of exactly two numbers appearing in six rolls of the die is 
$$\frac{\binom{6}{2} \cdot (2^6 - 2)}{6^6}$$

Exactly three numbers appear:

There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways for three of the six numbers to appear.  On each of the six rolls of the die, there are three possible outcomes, giving $3^6$ sequences containing these three numbers.  However, we have counted the sequences in which not all three of the numbers appear.  There are $\binom{3}{2}$ ways for two of the numbers to appear.  For each such pair, there are $2^6$ sequences, of which two consist of sequences in which one number is rolled all six times.  Thus, there are $\binom{3}{2}(2^6 - 2)$ sequences in which exactly two of the three numbers appear.  The number of sequences in which exactly one of the three numbers appears is $3$.  Hence, the probability that exactly three of the numbers appear is 
$$\frac{\binom{6}{3}[3^6 - \binom{3}{2}(2^6 - 2) - 3]}{6^6}$$

My thanks to @bof for clarifying my thinking about the first problem.  Any errors that remain are entirely my responsibility.

Comment: @bof You are correct since there are two excluded sequences for each of the $\binom{6}{2}$ ways of selecting two of the six numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your explanation really reinforced my understanding of difference between permutations and combinations.

Answer (score 0):

For two groups:

There are $6\choose 2$ ways of selecting the 2 groups. There are ${6\choose 2}-2$ ways to for 6 dice to roll those numbers.

Can you work it out for 3 groups?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. But could you explain why "-2"? I am still confused.

Comment: You have to remove the cases where there is only 1 group.

Comment: So that's how it's done! Then the 3 group is 5*4-3? Am I right? BTW, how do you use MathML?

Comment: Not quite - there are $6\choose 3$ ways to choose the sets and ${6\choose3}-{6\choose2}$ ways to fill them so there are no non-empty sets.

Comment: Search this site or its meta for MathML tutorial

Comment: Finally got it. As a rookie, Counting really afflicts me ;). Why it is a piece of cake for you, but a stumbling block for me? Thanks a lot, I will search the meta for MathML.

Comment: Why is it $\binom62-2$ and not $2^6-2$?

Answer (score -1):

Why can't we use the multinomial formula? We want to have a sequence of 2 repeated elements 3 each. This sounds like $\frac{6!}{3!*3!}$, right? 
For example we have {1,1,1,2,2,2} or a combination of this. Then we get $\frac{6!}{3!*3!}$ since we have 2 sets of 3 repeated elements and then we divide by the sample space times 6 (there are six possibilities). The result seems to be incorrect using this method. I tried using a 3^3 tree and it seemed ok. Any thoughts?